# Canvas. Рисование

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas, рисование

Хотел сделать на jsfiddle фидл, в котором рисуется квадрат каждый раз меняя свое направление. Но мне не очень нравится его поведение:

- Он постоянно меняет свои размеры
- Движется почти на одном месте

ссылка: http://jsfiddle.net/Rony_04/s2ukad90/35/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var width = 10;
var height = 10;
var x = 300;
var y = 200;
var step = 5;
/*
var dimensions = [
    'right',
  'left',
  'up',
  'down'
]
*/
var dimension;

ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";

setInterval(function () {
    dimension = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  switch (dimension) {
    case 0: 
        x += step;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
      break;
    case 1:
        x -= step;
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
      break;
    case 2:
        y -= step;
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
      break;
    case 3:
        y += step;
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
      break;
  }

    position += step;
}, 60);
```

Comment: Ну правильно, вы же каждый раз даете ему новые размеры, сами же пишите `ctx.fillRect(x, y, x + width, y + height);`, а `x` при этом меняете  `x += step;`. Какого поведения вы ожидали?))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko но ведь 3-м и 4-м параметром указываются координаты правого нижнего угла или я неправ?

Comment: Нет, не правы. 3 и 4 аргументы - это ширина и высота. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillrect.asp

Comment: Спасибо забыл )